# Make parallax scroll start when the image is in view

Tags: javascript, html, css

I followed this example to create a parallax inside my bootstrap columns, however my image is not at the top of the page so when I scroll down enough to see the image it is scrolled halfway through. I'm not very good at JavaScript so I'm not sure how to go about it. Can I "pause" the parallax until the image is in view?

This is the example I followed.

https://codepen.io/alberkko/pen/jONrwVv

HTML

```
<section id="twoImages" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="parallax"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://placebear.com/715/470" alt="shoe newspaper">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

CSS

```
body {
margin-bottom: 50em;
}

#twoImages {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  .col-md-6 {
   padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .parallax {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("https://placebear.com/715/470");
    /* Full height */
    height: 100%;
    /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
    /*background-attachment: fixed;*/
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
  }
}
```

JS

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict()
$(window).scroll(function(){
var scroll = $(this).scrollTop()
$(".parallax").css({"background-position":"0px "+scroll/2+"px"})
})
```

Comment: Your image is not at the top of the page because you have a lot of `<br>` tags in your code.

Comment: But the image not being at the top is not the problem. I don't actually want my image at the top of the page.